# jQuery UI selectable- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

I know I'm doing something wrong with the jQuery UI selectable code but I can't figure out exactly what. Also, how can I condense the two parts of the jQuery UI selectable code into one function?

Thank you!

HTML:

```
<ul id="monthPicker">
    <li class="month ui-selectable">January</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">February</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">March</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">April</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">May</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">June</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">July</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">August</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">September</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">October</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">November</li>
    <li class="month ui-selectable">December</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //works
    $('.month').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('picked');
    });

    //doesn't work 
    $('.month').selectable({ 
        selected: function(event, ui) { 
            if($(this).hasClass('picked')){
                $(this).removeClass('picked');
            }                       
            else{
                $(this).addClass('picked');
            }
        }
    });

    //doesn't work
     $('.month').selectable({   
        unselected:function(event, ui) { 
            if($(this).hasClass('picked')){
                $(this).removeClass('picked');
            }                       
            else{
                $(this).addClass('picked');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `selectable` on the parent element, not the children:

```
$('#monthPicker').selectable();
```

The selected items are then given the class `ui-selected` when the user selects them.

If you want to style the list items (`<li>` elements), they are given the class `ui-selectee`.